# Can't find any recursion in my file that causes Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, recursion, jquery-select2

Heres my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="../resources/js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../resources/select2-4.0.3/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../resources/select2-4.0.3/dist/css/select2.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../resources/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../resources/d3/d3.button.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Database Heat Map</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="head">
      <h1>Database Heat Map</h1>
      <div>
        <div>
          <h3>Schema</h3>
          <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="schema" id="schema">
            <option></option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>Table</h3>
          <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="table" id="table">
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The way that my select boxes are set up is that the second select box populates depending on what is selected in the first. Each Schema in the first drop down has their own sets of unique tables.

Here's my JavaScript/Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {//Load in json file using d3

getSchema();

$("#schema").change(function() {
    var e = document.getElementById("schema");
    var selectedSchema = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(selectedSchema)
    if (selectedSchema != "") {
        getTable(schema);
    }
})
function getSchema() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "heatmap.py",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {get: "schema"},
        success: function(results) {
            console.log(results);
            populateSchemaDropDown(results);
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("schema error");
        }
    })
}

function getTable(schema) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "heatmap.py",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {findTables: schema},
        success: function(results) {
            console.log(results);
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("table error")
        }
    })
}

function populateSchemaDropDown(schema) {
    $('#schema').select2({
        placeholder: "--Select One--",
        allowClear: true,
        data: schema,
        dropdownAutoWidth: true
    })
}

function populateTableDropDown(table) {
    $("#table").select2({
        placeholder: "--Select One--",
        allowClear: true,
        disabled: true
    })
}
```

The first dropdown box populates just fine, but whenever I click an option, it logs the name of the option like it's supposed to but I keep getting an Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded error from jquery

Here is the python file as well (ignore indent syntax, it's not pasting correctly):

```
def getSchema():
historicalRefreshStats = json.load(open(os.path.join(scriptDir, "historicalRefreshStats.json")))
schemas = []
for server in historicalRefreshStats:
    currentServer = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', server).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    for schema in historicalRefreshStats[currentServer]:
        currentSchema = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', schema).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        schemas.append(currentSchema)
return sorted(list(set(schemas)))

def getTables(schemaToFind):
historicalRefreshStats = json.load(open(os.path.join(scriptDir, "historicalRefreshStats.json")))
tables = []
for server in historicalRefreshStats:
    currentServer = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', server).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    for schema in historicalRefreshStats[currentServer]:
        currentSchema = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', schema).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        if schemaToFind == currentSchema:
            for table in historicalRefreshStats[currentServer][currentSchema]:
                tables.append(table)
return sorted(list(set(tables)))

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

if "get" in form:
    schemas = getSchema()
    print "Content-Type: text/json; charset=ISO-8859-1\n"
    print json.dumps(schemas)
elif "findTables" in form:
    schema = form["findTables"]
    tables = getTables(schema)
    print "Content-Type: text/json; charset=ISO-8859-1\n"
    print json.dumps(tables)
else:
    print "Content-Type: text/json; charset=ISO-8859-1\n"
    print json.dumps("error")
```

Any help is appreciated! I don't think it's doing anything recursively and I checked to make sure it wasn't the python response that was triggering the error. But it must be recursive if I'm getting the error, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calling getTable(schema) but schema is not defined, it should be selectedSchema, you also don't need that much code things could be a lot shorter, "less code = less problems"

like the change function for example: https://fiddle.jshell.net/____mmc/znqxaa2h/

```
$("#schema").change(function() {
   let selectedItem = $('#schema').select2('data')[0]
   ....
})
```

and the ajax call, you could embed the call in select2 https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax

Comment: you should include a copy of your code here in your answer as well